# Unknown attribute 'objc_boxable' ignored?

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang

I'm trying to typedef a struct and box it into a dictionary value. I tried this code [from the clang website](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#boxed-c-structures), but no dice:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((objc_boxable)) _SizeA {
    CGFloat height;
    CGFloat width;
} SizeA;
```

The typedef is warned `Unknown attribute 'objc_boxable' ignored.

Xcode 6.3 with iOS SDK 8.3 targeting 8.0. Is there a trick here I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're looking at the documentation for clang 3.7. But Apple is still back at clang 3.6.

```
$ xcrun clang --version
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
```

LLVM / clang 3.7 won't even be released until August.

Indeed, the feature you're trying to use was only just announced two days ago:

http://alexdenisov.github.io/nsvalue-and-boxed-expressions

Comment: Yup, that seems to be it. I was actually surprised it was a feature and thought I had just not been paying attention.

Comment: We seem to have been visited by Mister Boxable himself! @AlexDenisov, thanks for the URL edit.